# Is it possible to pass parameters to tinymce.init function using blade?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, tinymce, laravel-blade

I want to add default content based on database data to a tinymce editor:

Controller:

```
@if(isset($page_content))
    @forelse ($page_content['getMediaItems'] as $index => $item)
        @include('scripts.tinymce.tinymce-multiple-init',compact('index'))
    @empty
        {{'Woops..'}}
    @endforelse
@else
    @include('scripts.tinymce.tinymce-single-init')
@endif
```

So when there are multiple mediaitems i want to add the default text to the editor

Now i want the iteration (index) inside the init function on the include page:

```
tinymce.init({
   setup:function(ed) {
      //Stuff here
   },
   selector: '.js-editable-media',
   menubar:false,
   inline: true,
   plugins: "textcolor colorpicker",
   toolbar: [
    'undo redo forecolor'
   ],
   my_custom_variable: {!! $index !!}
});
```

Now {!! $index !!} only returning 0 and not the iteration number. But when i put index parameter ouside the function it is returning the correct numbers:

```
console.log({!! $index!!}); //showing correct iteration

tinymce.init({
  .....
  console.log({!! $index!!}); //showing only 0
});
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

`$index` is a key, that's why it's `0` in the first iteration. If you want to pass the value, you should pass `$item`:

```
@include('scripts.tinymce.tinymce-multiple-init', compact('item'))
```

And then:

```
my_custom_variable: {!! $item !!}
```

Also, it's a bad practice to hardcode PHP inside JS. Consider other ways to pass the data.

Comment: Actually i want the iteration key of each item not the item, now it's only returning 0, but when i console.log({!! $index !!}) outside the tinymce.init function it is returning the correct numbers:

console.log({!! $index !!}); //Showing the correct numbers

tinymce.init({
 .....
});

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to achieve then. Please try to explain what exactly you want to get, what numbers and where you want to get those.

Comment: Updated my question hope you understand it better now

Comment: Maybe the problem is you're trying to initialize tinymce multiple times, but it only initializes once? If this is the case, you'll need to [use different elements for each tinymce editor](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/multiple-editors/).

Comment: I want to add default content based on the object that has been sent with the forelse. Even when i change 'index' to 'item' it still returning 4times the same content